# A “Home" app keeps popping up. What does it mean?

Tags: ios, homekit

With iOS 16, my iPad got an app called "Home".  It just pops up randomly as an annoyance.

I am trying to figure out what makes it pop up.  I can't reproduce any of my theories, a swipe from the right side?  Touching an edge while using thumbprint scanner as passcode?

I swear it just happens randomly as I walk down the street.  Could that actually be so? If so, is that a home that has been properly set up for HomeKit, or do they just happen to own a device capable of HomeKit and haven't configured it?  If the latter, is that a security vulnerability for them?